# TPU node creation in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, terraform-provider-gcp, gcp-ai-platform-training

I have been trying to create TPU nodes from the console and it doesn't create a VM in the instances sections and also cannot SSH into the VM. Do you know how to create a GCP TPU from the console.

Answer (score 0):

[Creating a Cloud TPU in the Google Cloud console](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/managing-tpus-tpu-vm#creating_a_cloud_tpu_in_the_google_cloud_console)

1. Navigate to the Google Cloud console.
2. From the navigation menu, select Compute Engine > TPUs.
3. Click CREATE TPU NODE.
4. In the Name box, type a TPU instance name.
5. In the Zone box, select the zone in which to create the TPU.
6. Under TPU Configuration, select either TPU VM or TPU Node. The TPU configuration determines whether you create the TPU as a TPU VM or a TPU Node.
7. For TPU type, select the TPU type you want to create.
8. For TPU software version, select the software version. When creating a Cloud TPU VM, the TPU software version specifies the version of the TPU runtime to install. When creating a Cloud TPU Node, the TPU software version allows you to choose the ML framework installed on the node's VM. No other settings are required.
9. Click CREATE to create your resources.

Comment: I am quiet new with TPU s here so how can we use this TPU node ???

Comment: Should we SSH into the node...because I tried SSH and it shows me resource not found error and is it possible to connect the node to the VM.